# Visual Studio white background theme for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, intellij-idea

I *hate* the Java IDE's and want the feeling of safety that looking at the editor in Visual Studio gives me.

Is there a way I can get a Visual Studio theme, the normal one with the white background, and not the one with the black background, that I can import into IntelliJ IDEA to make it look like Visual Studio's syntax coloring?

Comment: I'm not an Intellij-idea user, but it seems like you can get themes [here](http://color-themes.com/) and a specific version of what I think you're looking for might be [this](http://color-themes.com/?view=theme&id=563a1a6780b4acf11273ae55)

Comment: @AssaultingCuccos Thanks so much. I'd checked that website and browsed through several of them but the one you link to comes close. I'll use that one. Thank you much much.

Comment: i would say that by default intellij already provides a light  (white background) shema isn't it? maybe you selected the Darcula scheme and you are not aware? If you go to "Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme", what do you see there?

Comment: I know about the Dracula one and I didn't want it. It's the black background one.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 what i asked is if you checked which one you had selected. intellij provides a default white theme aside from Darcula (Darcula is just one alternative). If you go to the settings i said, which alternatives you see there?

Comment: The *Default* one.

Comment: strange. which version of intellij are you using? and what do you see in "Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance"?

Comment: I see 3 themes: **Dracula**, **IntelliJ** and **Windows**. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1.

Comment: i have same version (but MAC) with intellij theme on appearance (it's listed as default in my case) and default in color scheme; and it's white not black. So don't know, or it's an os difference or maybe you overwrote color on the default theme by mistake? (not saying you did, but i cannot think of more alternatives). if picking an extra color scheme from the web another comment suggested then it's fine; but there is something that does not match :) On the "color scheme" section you can do a Reset over a scheme to ensure it is the predefined one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was originally posted as a comment, but it seems to have answered the question so I'll post it here as well for completeness.

I'm not an Intellij-idea user, but it seems like you can get themes [here](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes). [Editor's note: there used to be two links, but the website currently redirects to a GH repo in a way that makes the second link untracable. Ask OP for a new link]